# Deferred object not containing exact values in json object

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-deferred

I am creating one javascript library. In that I am using deferred methods for asynchronous call.
But the thing is, if I log the output json object is not showing all the items. But if I expand the object then it is showing actual values. Look the below screenshot.
[image]

In this `console.log` showing that subFolders object initially contains 0 elements, but if I expand the object then subFolders containing two elements. This output object is coming from multiple asynchronous calls. Following is my code

```
RESTQueries.getFilesFromFolders = function(){
    var execute = function(libraryName){
        var libraryItems={rootFolder:[],subFolders:[]};
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var _url = makeProperUrl();
        var itemsInRootFolder = getItemsFromFolder(libraryName,'files');
        itemsInRootFolder.then(function(data){
            var tempArray = [];
            if(typeof(data.d.results)!='undefined' && data.d.results.length>0)
            {

                for(var i =0;i<data.d.results.length;i++)
                {

                    tempArray.push({"name":data.d.results[i].Name});

                }
            }
            libraryItems.rootFolder.push(tempArray);
        }).then(function(){
            var subFolders = getItemsFromFolder(libraryName,'folders');
            subFolders.then(function(data){
                for(var item in data.d.results){
                    var fName = data.d.results[item].Name;
                    if(fName!='Forms')
                    {
                        var subFolderItems = getItemsFromFolder(libraryName+"/"+fName ,'files');
                        subFolderItems.then(function(subItems,link){
                            var actualFolderName = link.split("/")[1];
                            var tempArray={}; 
                            var tempArray2 = [];
                            for(var i=0;i<subItems.d.results.length;i++){
                                tempArray2.push({"name":subItems.d.results[i].Name});
                            }
                            tempArray[actualFolderName]=tempArray2;
                            tempArray2="";
                            libraryItems.subFolders.push(tempArray);                            
                        });
                    }
                }
            });         
        }).then(function(){
            deferred.resolve(libraryItems);
        });
        return deferred;
    };
    return{
        execute:execute
    }
}();
```

I am executing this function like,

```
RESTQueries.getFilesFromFolders.execute('HelpDocuments').then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Why json object is behaving like this? Where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 0):

check if this code work for you

```js
RESTQueries.getFilesFromFolders = function(){
    var execute = function(libraryName){
        var libraryItems={rootFolder:[],subFolders:[]};
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var _url = makeProperUrl();
        var itemsInRootFolder = getItemsFromFolder(libraryName,'files');
        itemsInRootFolder.then(function(data){
            var tempArray = [];
            if(typeof(data.d.results)!='undefined' && data.d.results.length>0)
            {

                for(var i =0;i<data.d.results.length;i++)
                {

                    tempArray.push({"name":data.d.results[i].Name});

                }
            }
            libraryItems.rootFolder.push(tempArray);
            

         var subFolders = getItemsFromFolder(libraryName,'folders');
                    subFolders.then(function(data){
                        for(var item in data.d.results){
                            var fName = data.d.results[item].Name;
                            if(fName!='Forms')
                            {
                                var subFolderItems = getItemsFromFolder(libraryName+"/"+fName ,'files');
                                subFolderItems.then(function(subItems,link){
                                    var actualFolderName = link.split("/")[1];
                                    var tempArray={}; 
                                    var tempArray2 = [];
                                    for(var i=0;i<subItems.d.results.length;i++){
                                        tempArray2.push({"name":subItems.d.results[i].Name});
                                    }
                                    tempArray[actualFolderName]=tempArray2;
                                    tempArray2="";
                                    libraryItems.subFolders.push(tempArray);   
                                    deferred.resolve(libraryItems);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });             
            
            
            
        });
        return deferred;
    };
    return{
        execute:execute
    }
}();
```

Comment: Earlier I tried in this way also. No change in result

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know a console could behave that way. Maybe it's better in other browsers.

We can't fix the console but we can fix the code, which needs some work to purge the [Deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/) and, more importantly, to acknowledge the asynchronism of the two inner `getItemsFromFolder()` calls.

The pattern isn't the simplest but you should end up with something like this :

```
RESTQueries.getFilesFromFolders = function(){
    var execute = function(libraryName) {
        return getItemsFromFolder(libraryName, 'files').then(function(data) {
            var tempArray;
            if(data.d && data.d.results) {
                tempArray = $.map(data.d.results, function(r) {
                    return { 'name': r.Name };
                });
            }
            return { rootFolder: [tempArray] || [] };
        }).then(function(libraryItems) {
            return getItemsFromFolder(libraryName, 'folders').then(function(data) {
                var promises = [];
                if(data.d && data.d.results) {
                    $.each(data.d.results, function(r) {
                        var fName = r.Name;
                        if(fName != 'Forms') {
                            promises.push(getItemsFromFolder(libraryName + "/" + fName, 'files').then(function(subItems, link) {
                                if(subItems.d && subItems.d.results) {
                                    var tempObj = {};
                                    tempObj[link.split("/")[1]] = $.map(subItems.d.results, function(r) {
                                        return { 'name': r.Name };
                                    });
                                    return tempObj;
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                }
                return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
                    return $.extend(libraryItems, {
                        subFolders: Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).filter(function(p) {
                            return !!p; //filter out any nulls
                        })
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };
    return {
        execute:execute
    }
}();
```

I made a heap of mods and may well have made mistakes, so be prepared to do some debugging.

Comment: It is not only appearing in console. If i try find length like `console.log(data.subFolders.length);` then it is showing `0` instead of 2

Comment: That's not surprising when the length actually *is* zero. What is surprising is that the console should report length zero and length 2 simultaneously, in its expanded and unexpanded representations.

Comment: And, with the code as it was in the question, data.subFolders.length should have been zero in both cases. The reason being that the asyncronisms of the inner `getItemsFromFolder()` calls are not taken into account in the resolution of the Deferred. You don't say whether or not you have tried my code.

Comment: I am confusing to use your code. But I will try to implement this. I think you are not returning a `deferred` object right!! you are returning just json object

Comment: In the `$.when()` function from where the `arguments` variable is coming? do you meant by `Array.prototype.slice.apply(promises)` ?

Comment: No, look carefully. The first line of `.execute()` starts `return getItemsFromFolder(...`. That is a promise. After that is a complex set of .thens that modify that original promise.

Comment: I use **[.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)** twice. `$.when.apply(null, promises)` causes `$.when()` to operate on the array `promises`.  `Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)` converts the array-like **[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)** into a proper array. This all very standard stuff - more than beginners level but not particularly advanced. I suggest you follow the references and do some background reading.

Comment: Understood. But the returned object is promise right! I used then function to it like `RESTQueries.getFilesFromFolders.execute('HelpDocuments').then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
  });` but the console value is coming as `undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65282/discussion-between-roamer-1888-and-mihir).